# Custom JavaScript in WordPress Contact Form 7 not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to hide the contact form after it passes validation and is submitted. I want to do this with a simple custom JavaScript function.

The thing is, the console keeps informing me that my JS function is undefined. At first I had thought that this might be happening because I'm not enqueing the *.js correctly, but that's not the case - my custom.js is clearly visible in the page's source code, and its contents match what I'd put inside.

Here's my code so far.

functions.php (child theme)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'for_contact' );
function for_contact() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'contactFormHide',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
}
```

custom.js

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    function contactFormHide (){
        $('.section_inner_margin').css('display','none');
        $('.section_inner').html('<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">Your message has been sent.</div>');
    }

});
```

Contact Form 7 settings (Additional Settings tab)

```
on_sent_ok: "contactFormHide()"
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Correction in the code. Define $ in the function.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

function contactFormHide(){
            $('.section_inner_margin').css('display','none');
            $('.section_inner').html('<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">Your message has been sent.</div>');
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I have tried passing $ as the function's argument, but the error is stll there.

Comment: what was the error in console? can you put that error here?

Comment: Sure. It was `TypeError: contactFormHide is undefined`. The thing is - custom.js is included correctly, and I can see it in the page's compiled source code. When I open it, sure enough, the function is there. I have no idea why WP is not seeing it.

Comment: Again, sorry for taking this long to reply. Now the error is different - $ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Ahmed Ginani's solution will likely work but have you also tried passing `$` as a parameter within a completely self-contained function as follows:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";

        function contactFormHide (){
            $('.section_inner_margin').css('display','none');
            $('.section_inner').html('<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ok" style="display: block;" role="alert">Your message has been sent.</div>');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This way, you're passing the `jQuery` object as an argument to the `function`. This means we can use `$` locally within the function without it conflicting with other scripts / frameworks / libraries, etc...

Comment: Interestingly enough, this has worked for me in another, non-WP, problem of the same sort (conflicting *.js). Here, however, the error persists. :\